# Erorr with post request

Tags: reactjs, api, post, request

I am trying to do a challenge where I have to send this data through a **post request** to http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/

> ```
> email: challenge@alkemy.org
> password: react
> ```

```
const baseUrl = "http://challenge-react.alkemy.org/";

const user = {
    'email': 'challenge@alkemy.org',
    'password': 'react'
    
}

const getToken =  async () => {
    fetch(baseUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        request: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => response.json()) 
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

export default getToken;
```

For some reason that I can't understand, it is returning this to me

> {error: "Please provide valid email and password"}

I don't know if my problem is with my function or what.
If I make this same request via postman, it returns the token I need

Answer (score 0):

`request` should be `headers`.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will ever work in the browser because it keeps forcing the requests over `HTTPS`, erroring with: `(unknown) POST https://challenge-react.alkemy.org/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. You can check for yourself by opening the console tab in developer tools (F12 on Chrome).

```js
function App() {
  const baseUrl = "http://challenge-react.alkemy.org";

  const user = {
    email: "challenge@alkemy.org",
    password: "react",
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(baseUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err)); // "oh, no!"
  }, []);
  return <div />;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```